# Accessing C++ class member in inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, inline-assembly

**Question:** How can I access a member variable in assembly from within a non-POD class?

---

**Elaboration:**

I have written some inline assembly code for a class member function but what eludes me is how to access class member variables.  I've tried the **offsetof** macro but this is a non-POD class.

The current solution I'm using is to assign a pointer from global scope to the member variable but it's a messy solution and I was hoping there was something better that I dont know about.

**note:** I'm using the G++ compiler.  A solution with Intel syntax Asm would be nice but I'll take anything.

**example of what I want to do** (intel syntax):

```
class SomeClass
{
  int* var_j;
  void set4(void)
  {
    asm("mov var_j, 4"); // sets pointer SomeClass::var_j to address "4"
  }
};
```

**current hackish solution:**

```
int* global_j;
class SomeClass
{
  int* var_j;
  void set4(void)
  {
    asm("mov global_j, 4"); // sets pointer global_j to address "4"
    var_j = global_j;       // copy it back to member variable :(
  }
};
```

Those are crude examples but I think they get the point across.

Comment: Have you tried looking at a disassembly of what the G++ compiler outputs with the code `var_j = 4;` or something like that?

Comment: using a global pointer isn't threadsafe as it's value might be overwritten before reassigning the saved value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("movl $4,%[v]" : [v] "+m" (var_j)) ;
```

**Edited to add:** The assembler does accept Intel syntax, but the compiler doesn't know it, so this trick won't work using Intel syntax (not with g++ 4.4.0, anyway).

Comment: This is very interesting. This syntax is not part of the standard GCC inline assembly HOWTO. Where did you learn about it?

Comment: "Using the GNU Compiler Collection" (For gcc version 4.5.1), Section 6.39 "Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands". Available at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/. (Actually I can't seem to find my version on the web -- in this document it's Section 6.41.)

Comment: You can compile with `-masm=intel` to use Intel syntax in inline asm.  But generally don't; AT&T syntax with operand-size overrides attached to mnemonics instead of operands is usually easier for inline asm.

Answer (score 3):

```
class SomeClass
{
  int* var_j;
  void set4(void)
  {
    __asm__ __volatile__("movl $4, (%0,%1)"
:
: "r"(this), "r"((char*)&var_j-(char*)this)
:
);
  }
};
```

This might work too, saving you one register:

```
    __asm__ __volatile__("movl $4, %1(%0)"
:
: "r"(this), "i"((char*)&var_j-(char*)this)
:
);
```

In fact, since the offset of `var_j` wrt. `this` should be known at compile time, the second option is the way to go, even if it requires some tweaking to get it working. (I don't have access to a g++ system right now, so I'll leave this up to you to investigate.)

And don't ever underestimate the importance of `__volatile__`. Took more of my time that I'd liked to track down bugs that appeared because I missed the volatile keyword and the compiler took it upon itself to do strange things with my assembly.