# Inline assembly troubles

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, intel, inline-assembly

I tried to compile with **GCC** inline assembly code which compiled fine with **MSVC**, but got the following errors for basic operations:

```
// var is a template variable in a C++ function
__asm__
{
    mov edx, var //error: Register name not specified for %edx
    push ebx //error: Register name not specified for %ebx
    sub esp, 8 //error: Register name not specified for %esp
}
```

After looking through [documentation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html) covering the topic, I found out that I should probably convert (even if I am only interested in x86) **Intel** style assembly code to **AT&T** style. However, after trying to use **AT&T** style I got even more weird errors:

```
mov var, %edx //error: Expected primary-expression before % token
mov $var, edx //error: label 'LASM$$s' used but not defined
```

I should also note that I tried to use **LLVM-GCC**, but it failed miserably with internal errors after encountering inline assembly.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you specify more your environment and target? Xcode and Intel-based Macs?

Comment: XCode 3, Intel based Macs, 32-bits (hopefully the executable will somehow work in 64-bit in emulation mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ inline assembler is much more flexible than MSVC, and much more complicated. It treats an asm directive as a pseudo-instruction, which has to be described in the language of the code generator. Here is a working sample from my own code (for MinGW, not Mac):

```
// int BNASM_Add (DWORD* result, DWORD* a, int len)
//
//   result += a

int BNASM_Add (DWORD* result, DWORD* a, int len)
  {
  int carry ;
  asm volatile (
".intel_syntax\n"
"    clc\n"
"    cld\n"

"loop03:\n"
"    lodsd\n"
"    adc     [edx],eax\n"
"    lea     edx,[edx+4]\n"   // add edx,4 without disturbing the carry flag
"    loop    loop03\n"

"    adc     ecx,0\n"         // Return the carry flag (ecx known to be zero)
".att_syntax\n"
: "=c"(carry)                   // Output: carry in ecx
: "d"(result), "S"(a), "c"(len) // Input: result in edx, a in esi, len in ecx
) ;
  return carry ;
  }
```

You can find documentation at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm.

Comment: @Ryan: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583288/accessing-c-class-member-in-inline-assembly/4584046#4584046 for a code sample that accesses C++ variables.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I can't make this work - even trying to compile asm volatile ( ".intel_syntax\n" ); gives me a very strange error - "No such instruction: 'orl $-2147483648, -36(%ebp)', Error writing to -: Broken pipe

Comment: @Ryan: You have to switch back to ".att_syntax\n" at the end of the string. In your example, the code emitted by the compiler *after* your asm instruction is in AT&T syntax, but the assembler is still in Intel mode. Generate an asm listing with -S to see what's going on.

Comment: Actually, I still get the Broken pipe error... And if I use the -save_temps argument (-S seems to be already defined by XCode), there are no assembly listings for files with inline assembly... I think my problem is caused by using intel-style labels - should the code like asm volatile ( ".intel_syntax\n" "mov eax, var\n" "jmp myLabel\n" "_myLabel:\n" ".att_syntax\n"); work?

Comment: "jmp _myLabel\n", with an underscore. As for accessing `var`, you have to use AT&T syntax for that -- see my other answer. (There, `[v]` is a place-holder; you can use any identifier instead of `v`.)

Comment: Thanks again, Tony! I'm very sorry, but I still don't get it... Why wont't the following code work? var is input parameter, double *resultVar is an output parameter... asm volatile ( ".intel_syntax\n" "mov eax, var\n" "mov ecx, resultVar\n" "jmp _myLabel\n" "_myLabel:\n" ".att_syntax\n" :"=c"(resultVar) :"d"(s));

Comment: the code compiles fine when the label logic is removed, however during linking phase gcc fails to find var and resultVar...

Comment: I have no luck at all, can't compile even the following code: template <class W> inline void test_a(double *result, const W *data)
{
        double d = 0;
 double *pResult = &d;
 asm volatile (
 ".intel_syntax\n"
  "mov     edx, data\n"
  "mov     ecx, pResult\n"
 ".att_syntax\n"
 : "=c"(pResult)
 : "d"(data)
 );

 *result = *pResult;
}

Comment: I get the data / pResult 'referenced from:' linker error... Why?

Comment: Take the example from my other answer, and make it work for you. You won't find anything like "mov eax,var" in my code!

Answer (score 4):

For Apple's gcc you want `-fasm-blocks` which allows you to omit gcc's quoting requirement for inline asm and also lets you use Intel syntax.

```
// test_asm.c

int main(void)
{
    int var;

    __asm__
    {
        mov edx,var
        push ebx
        sub esp,8
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile this with:

```
$ gcc -Wall -m32 -fasm-blocks test_asm.c -o test_asm
```

Tested with gcc 4.2.1 on OS X 10.6.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul! If it's not too much to ask, can you please post a basic example of quoted assembly code...

Comment: Um, I tried to use the -masm=intel in Other C/C++ flags and got an error "Bad value (intel) for -masm= swithc"

Comment: @Ryan: sorry - I've been editing the answer - try `-masm=intel -fasm-blocks`, or for a more portable solution go for @TonyK's answer.

Comment: Don't know about other platforms, but both my ubuntu and cygwin gcc support `-masm=intel`

Comment: @Dani: sorry - it's the `fasm-blocks` that is Apple-specific - it enables you to omit the quotes and use a more MSVC-like asm syntax.

Comment: @Ryan: sorry - it took several iterations to get to something that actually works - please ignore previous comments and see updated answer above

Comment: @Ryan: no problem - @TonyK deserves the rep - it took me several false starts to come up with a half-decent answer