# Accessing class members from inline assembly in Visual C++

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

Here is my code:

```
void Graph::PutPixel(DWORD x, DWORD y, DWORD c)
{
    __asm 
    {
        Mov Eax, y
        Mov Ebx, _width
        Mul Ebx
        Add Eax, x
        Shl Eax, 2 // Multiply by four
        Add Eax, _buffer
        Mov Edi, Eax
        Mov Eax, c
        StosD
    }
}
```

Where _buffer and _width are Graph class members:

```
private:
    DWORD _width;
    DWORD* _buffer;
```

It does not work; I get 0 value from both variables, but they have some other values in fact.

I can fix it by copying class variables to local variables and using them:

```
void Graph::PutPixel(DWORD x, DWORD y, DWORD c)
{
    DWORD bufAddr = (DWORD)_buffer;
    DWORD w = _width;
    __asm 
    {
        Mov Eax, y
        Mov Ebx, w
        Mul Ebx
        Add Eax, x
        Shl Eax, 2 // Multiply by four
        Add Eax, bufAddr
        Mov Edi, Eax
        Mov Eax, c
        StosD
    }
}
```

What's the problem with direct usage? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried, in your first example, using `Mov Ebx, ._width` etc.

Comment: Here is one solution, still not very convenient: Mov Esi, this; Mov Ebx, [Esi]._width

Comment: You should be able to do this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y325bw3.aspx, just cannot call class methods.

Comment: @Kefir Your comment using the `this` pointer hints at the problem: you're working with a class and its member variables. And assembler is not C++, in assembler you'll do many things in smallest steps, so that seems to be your answer. What's inconvenient in that solution?

Comment: this seems to solve the problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583288/accessing-c-class-member-in-inline-assembly

Comment: @xmoex: Only that that's with GCC, which uses a completely different syntax for inline assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the off chance that you have something that really does need assembly (see Bo's answer), there is an article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fabdxz08%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on accessing C or C++ data in inline assembly blocks.

In your case we get:

```
void Graph::PutPixel(DWORD x, DWORD y, DWORD c)
{
    __asm 
    {
        mov ecx,this
        mov Eax, y
        mov Ebx, [ecx]Graph._width //alias ecx to type 'Graph' and access member
        mul Ebx
        add Eax, x
        shl Eax, 2
        add Eax, [ecx]._buffer //access member with bound alias
        mov Edi, Eax
        mov Eax, c
        stosd
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears your answer is old, although the information is good and still valid the link provided doesn't lead to any current material and thus may not be able to do more in this time. So I will add to your answer before.

Answer (score 4):

Why use assembly in the first place?!

Isn't this

```
void Graph::PutPixel(DWORD x, DWORD y, DWORD c)
{
    __asm 
    {
        Mov Eax, y
        Mov Ebx, _width
        Mul Ebx
        Add Eax, x
        Shl Eax, 2 // Multiply by four
        Add Eax, _buffer
        Mov Edi, Eax
        Mov Eax, c
        StosD
    }
}
```

the same as

```
DWORD* ptr = ((y * _width) + x) + _buffer;
*ptr = c;
```

Just storing `c` at a computed memory address.

---

Or, even simpler

```
_buffer[y * _width + x] = c;
```

Now we're talking!

Comment: I've taken this method as an example. It's the simplest one. Other methods like PutSprite are lot more complex and I want to have them in assembly. In fact, I'm trying to port my old DOS game to C++. All drawing methods are written in assembly and operate on memory buffer, so the only thing I need to change is how I output resulting in-memory picture to screen. I'd like to keep asm methods as they are, just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above from other answers, accessing the members of a class or struct in inline assembly using visual studio can be done like this. 
Source for more information is found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/accessing-c-or-cpp-data-in-asm-blocks?view=vs-2019 on the Microsoft website.

```
// InlineAssembler_Accessing_C_asm_Blocks.cpp
// processor: x86
#include <stdio.h>
struct first_type
{
   char *weasel;
   int same_name;
};

struct second_type
{
   int wonton;
   long same_name;
};

int main()
{
   struct first_type hal;
   struct second_type oat;

   __asm
   {
      lea ebx, hal
      mov ecx, [ebx]hal.same_name ; Must use 'hal'
      mov esi, [ebx].weasel       ; Can omit 'hal'
   }
   return 0;
}
```